# Mouse cursor randomly moving

Tags: mouse, cursor

I have this strange problem with mouse cursor moving slightly in all possible directions. I run a Win10 machine and it only seems to happen if I'm connected to the internet. I thought it could be a virus and I've checked my PC with various anti malware and spyware programmes. They didn't find anything suspicious. Process explorer also showed nothing strange.

The cursor seem to move in an incoherent fashion, it doesn't look like it is being controlled but it only happens with internet cable plugged in. I noticed this when my screensaver kept turning off for no reason. What could be haunting my machine?

PS: it seems to be happening randomly. it could move by a tiny bit after 15 minutes of not using my PC or after 2 hours

Answer (score 0):

From your question, we cannot get too many details of your setup, so I'll answer based on similar strange behaviour I found to happen in computers with touch screens that are plugged into outlets with no grounding.

In such cases, it seems that no proper grounding of the machine affects the proper working conditions of the screen resulting in odd behaviours as for example one finger creating a multitouch input, which influences mouse cursor behaviour.

It could be an electrical problem in your machine related with ethernet cable connection that might interfere with the touchpad or touch screen.

Comment: I'm sorry I definitely should have mentioned that my PC is a desktop without touch screen. Only mouse and keyboard